# Handling gocardless webhook with firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, function, gocardless

I'm using GoCardless (sandbox account) webhook for a billing project.
I've follow the steps on  [this guide](https://developer.gocardless.com/getting-started/partners/staying-up-to-date-with-webhooks/) using Nodejs locally (with ngrok) to handle the webhooks and it works, my intention is to use firebase functions as server, but when I deploy the code on firebase and test the code it throws 'timeout error', I don know if I'm missing something about firebase functions...
This is the code on firebase:

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const webhooks = require("gocardless-nodejs/webhooks");
    const webhookEndpointSecret = "xxxxxx";
    exports.events = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    if (request.method !== "POST") {
        response.writeHead(405);
        response.end();
        return;
    }
    let data = "";
    request.on("data", chunk => {
        data += chunk;
    });
    request.on("end", () => {
        try {
            const signatureHeader = request.headers["webhook-signature"];
            const events = webhooks.parse(
                data,
                webhookEndpointSecret,
                signatureHeader
            );
            events.forEach(event => {
                if (event.resource_type !== "mandates") {
                    //continue;
                }
                switch (event.action) {
                    case "created":
                        console.log(
                            `Mandate ${event.links.mandate} has been created, yay!`
                        );
                        break;
                    case "cancelled":
                        console.log(`Oh no, mandate ${event.links.mandate} was cancelled!`);
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log(`${event.links.mandate} has been ${event.action}`);
                }
            });
            response.writeHead(204);
            response.end();
        } catch (e) {
            response.writeHead(403);
            response.end();
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured out how was going on... the problem was that the 'data' variable was empty. I solved the problem getting the request body like this:

```
let data = request.rawBody.toString();
```

I hope this can be useful for someone else.